# Generating deterministic K - RFC 6979 - In BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm trying to copy some Python code such that it functions the same in BouncyCastle \ C#.

The code generates K to RFC 6979 spec I believe.

```
# get deterministic k
                sha_digest = hashlib.sha256(digest).digest()
            k = ecdsa.rfc6979.generate_k(self._sk.curve.generator.order(),
                                         self._sk.privkey.secret_multiplier,
                                         hashlib.sha256,
                                         sha_digest
                                         )
            # sign the message
            sigder = self._sk.sign_digest(digest, sigencode=ecdsa.util.sigencode_der, k=k)
```

The above code is in a loop and sha_digest is being modified in each loop.

Does Bouncycastle has a similar generate_k method somewhere that I'm able to call?

Comment: `k` can be determined in C#/BouncyCastle with [`HMacDsaKCalculator#NextK()`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/crypto/signers/HMacDsaKCalculator.cs#L100).

Comment: Yes, HmacDsaKCalculator, but probably not calling it directly, rather constructing an instance of ECDsaSigner with it. Depending on the semantics of the python code (which I don't know), the ECDsaSigner itself might need to be wrapped with a DsaDigestSigner.